# Connect to remote database over the internet from mobile app

Tags: delphi

I want to develop a mobile (Android and iOS) app with Delphi XE 8 that connect to local company server that has Firebird database over the internet and be able to query the database to get or update the data and I am looking to know only the methods and components that I should use in this mobile app.

For example if I will use REST what components or applications I should develop to communicate with the database ? should I use RemObject Data Abstract ?

Comment: Let me suggest you a couple of keywords for your google search "delphi rest samples" - maybe too easy and too straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use DataSnap to create the client and server application. It is also available in Firemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RemoteSQL from GoFast Soft? 
There is a simple (but a great) review of it on a Zarko's [blog](http://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/speed-up-your-delphi-database-apps-using-remote-sql/)

Comment: thanks, but if I used datasnap (http) is it going to be fast enough ?

Comment: it depends, if connecting from mobile device to DBMS,
you'll probably want that speed access to the data is invariant given 
the distance between device and DBMS. If fetching/sending a small amount
of data from/to DBMS server than it will be enough to choose Datasnap. In other circumstances, where you want your speed access to be optimized regards data,  you should consider some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at getting UniDAC https://www.devart.com/unidac/
They have native components for Andriod and iOS that you can drop on your form and build your connection without the need to include any libraries.

I only use MySQL so I make use of MyDAC but it works the same for UniDAC.

1. You can use the TUniConnection to setup your connection to any database server (not just Firebird).
2. And for the queries you use the TUniQuery

You can use all the other components they work on the same logic as the ADO components that I am sure you are familiar with.
Hope this helps

Comment: If you want to keep your data safe don't do that